# NextJs React Hook Form empty useFormContext

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I have error during NextJs Build on my Inputs using React Hook Form :

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/tool/formComponents/select". Read more: 

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'register' of '(0 , o.useFormContext)(...)' as it is null.
```

I can't figure it out why it fail.. Everything is ok during development, only fail at build. FormProvider is wrapping every Inputs :

```
const methods = useForm<IFormData>({ defaultValues: requestObj });

...
return (
     <FormProvider {...methods}>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} defaultValues={requestObj ?? null}>
              <Input/>
...
```

Here is my Input component :

```
export default function Input({
  name,
  label,
  spanBottom = "",
  noBorder = false,
  ...rest
}: {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  spanBottom?: string;
  noBorder?: boolean;
  [key: string]: any;
}) {
  const methods = useFormContext();

  if(!methods) {
    throw new Error('useFormContext() is required');
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
      {label && <label>{label}</label>}
      <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
        <input
          {...methods.register(name)}
          {...rest}
          className={`${spanBottom && styles.inputSpan} ${
            noBorder && styles.noBorder
          }`}
        />
        {spanBottom && <span>{spanBottom}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```